# Only part of functions see class arguments

Tags: python

So when I load module and launch function init() everything works good, but when init() starts a another function in the same class (Clock()) via dictionary, it returns me:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lcd'

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
import time
import os
import sys
from time import gmtime, strftime, sleep, time
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
# Initialize the LCD using the pins

class screen:
    lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()
    buttons = ( (LCD.SELECT, 0),
                (LCD.LEFT,   1),
                (LCD.UP,     2),
                (LCD.DOWN,   3),
                (LCD.RIGHT,  4) )

    button = 0
    is_pressed = 0
    pos = (0,0) # x,y
    menu_height = (0)
    frame = 0
    frameperiod = 0
    def Clock(self):
        print "Clock"
        self.lcd.clear()
        self.lcd.message('Zegar\n')
        self.lcd.message(strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        #Force update!
    menu = {
        (0,0) : Clock,

    }
    def process(self):
        print "Process"
        sleep(100)
        for tbutton in buttons:
            if self.lcd.is_pressed(tbutton[0]):
                is_pressed=1
        if is_pressed==1: #len(array)
            #move
            if button[1] == 1 and pos[1] == 0 and pos[0]>0:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1 #left
            if button[1] == 4 and pos[1] == 0 and pos[0]<len(menu_height):
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1 #right
            if button[1] == 2 and pos[1]>0:
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1 #up
            if button[1] == 3 and pos[1]<=menu_height[pos[0]]:
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            is_pressed=0
        print pos
        if frame==0:
            self.menu[pos](pos[1])
        #todo button[1]=1?
        is_pressed=0
    def init(self):
        self.lcd.set_color(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        self.lcd.clear()
        self.lcd.message("Inicjalizacja")
        print "Init"
        self.menu[(0,0)](0)
        return
```

Comment: Do you mean `__init__` instead `init`?

Comment: show us the place where you call `init`

Comment: No, I don't intend to make it constructor, it's just an usual function

Comment: code: http://pastebin.com/6wTLAReg

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Clock`, you're not calling it on the object.  You're calling it as a free-standing function.  Therefore, you need to provide `self` as a parameter.

```
self.menu[(0, 0)](self)
```

I'm not sure why you were trying to pass `0` there.  `Clock` doesn't expect an `int` parameter.